# NetworkError Fetch React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Возникла ошибка, которую я без понятия, как решать. Надеюсь вы смогли бы помочь с ней.

Есть Api сервер на Express, а также Client-Side на React. Использую свой hook для отправки запросов:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react"

import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import { useMessage } from '../hooks/message.hook';

export const useHttp = () => {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [error, setError] = useState(null)
const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
const message = useMessage()

const request = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
    setLoading(true)

    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
        headers['Authorization'] = auth.token
    }

    try {
        if (body) {
            body = JSON.stringify(body)
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        }

        const response = await fetch(url, {method, body, headers})

        if (auth.isAuthenticated && response.statusText === 'Unauthorized') {
            auth.token = null
            auth.isAuthenticated = false
            auth.logout()
            setLoading(false)
            
            message('Пожалуйста, войдите в аккаунт')
            return (<Redirect to="/" />)
        }

        const data = await response.json()

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(data.message || 'Что-то пошло не так')
        }

        setLoading(false)

        return data
    } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false)
        setError(e.message)
        throw e
    }
}, [auth, message])

const clearError = useCallback(() => {setError(null)}, [])

return {loading, request, error, clearError}
}
```

Код, который делает запрос:

```
const createHandler = async () => {
    try {
        await request('/api/note/create', 'POST', {...createForm})
        message('Заметка создана')
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

В Firefox отображается, что просто не пришел ответ, но есть ошибка networkerror when attempting to fetch resource

В Chrome отображается, что запрос заблокирован

В чём проблема? CORS? Но почему тогда остальные запросы работают? Всё запущено на localhost.

Самое интересное - то, что запрос на сервер приходит и он успешно обрабатывается, но Fetch говорит другое :/

Comment: Все остальные запросы работают, проблема именно с этим
/api/login работает
/api/register работает
/api/account работает
/api/notes/create нет

Comment: Также если отправлять запрос с 
/main, а не с /main/create - всё работает :/

Comment: Мне кажется, что происходит ошибка из-за редиректа. По непонятной причине, происходит редирект на страницу /main/create

Answer (score 0):

Всё до безобразия просто. Оказалось нужно было убрать type submit, ибо это вызывало обычное поведение и редирект, а Fetch выдавал ошибку.